API Gateway API key file upload using Terraform
Is there any Terraform resource to upload an AWS API Gateway gateway key file?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-key-file-format.html

I think you would need to get Terraform to iterate over the contents of the file, and create an aws_api_gateway_api_key resource for each row in the file, which is basically the same thing AWS is doing when you upload the file. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_api_key

That is the custom ways to achieve the same. But curious  to know direct way to provide the file and generate set of keys.

What I'm saying is that I looked at the Terraform provider, and I don't see a way to do that. There doesn't appear to be an API exposed by Amazon to directly upload the CSV file, it appears to only be a feature of the AWS web UI. So what I said above is the only option I can see to accomplish this using Terraform.
